# link libssl got undefined reference error after upgrading ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, libssl

My build works correctly before, but after upgrading ubuntu 18.04, it is wrong now.

```
c++  ... main.cc.o -o bin/bcDebug -rdynamic -pthread -lcppcms -lbooster -lboost_system -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -lcryptopp -lta_lib
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `EVP_aria_256_gcm@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestVerify@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `EVP_aria_128_gcm@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `ERR_load_strings_const@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `RAND_priv_bytes@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `conf_ssl_name_find@OPENSSL_1_1_0i'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `X509_get_signature_info@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_new_raw_private_key@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `RSA_pkey_ctx_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `conf_ssl_get@OPENSSL_1_1_0i'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `conf_ssl_get_cmd@OPENSSL_1_1_0i'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestSign@OPENSSL_1_1_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my c++ version:

c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: You can try adding the flags `-lssl` and possibly also `-lcrypto`

Comment: @Galik thanks. add -lcrypto option works.